# Сложная выборка с помощью UNION

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Составляю сложный запрос к базе данных. Полей много, поэтому сокращаю их.
Привожу схематику запроса:

```
SELECT 
    id, title, date
    FROM posts
    WHERE category = "'.$cat.'" // выбираем статьи, у кот. категория = $cat
    ORDER BY date DESC // сортируем по дате добавления 
    LIMIT 10 AS t1 // вывести 10 статей
UNION
SELECT
    id, from_post, to_user, comment, date // выбираем комментарии к статье, ...
    FROM comments
    WHERE from_post = t1.id // ... у которых from_post = id статьи
    ORDER BY date DESC // также сортируем по дате добавления 
    LIMIT 4 AS t2 // вывести 4 последних комментария
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM comments // а так же получаем кол-во всех комментариев для этой статьи
    WHERE from_post = t1.id AS cnt
UNION
    SELECT id, name, avatar // и выбираем имя и аватарку автора каждого комментария
    FROM usercom WHERE id = t2.to_user
```

Каким образом изменить запрос, что бы выполнялась следующая задача:
Вывести 10 статей, к каждой статье по 4 комментария (плюс колличество всех комментариев к этой статье), если они есть, и имя с аватаркой автора для каждого комментария.

Comment: Не стоит лепить вывод постов с комментами в в один запрос. Это совершенно разные сущности.

Comment: Сложный запрос это 4 простых обьеденненых union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Юнион разных по структуре таблиц конечно сделать невозможно. Если уж так приспичило сделать это обязательно одним запросом - можно так:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT P.id
     , p.title
     , p.`date`
     , count(C.id)
FROM
  posts P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments C  ON C.from_post = P.id
WHERE category = "'.$cat.'"
GROUP BY
  P.id
, p.title
, p.`date`
  LIMIT 10) Q1

  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT C1.from_post AS post, C1.id, C1.`comment`, C1.`date`, C1.to_user, U.name, U.avatar
FROM
  comments C1
    JOIN Usercom U ON U.id = C1.to_user
WHERE
  (
SELECT count(*)
FROM
  Comments C2
WHERE
  C2.from_post = C1.from_post
  AND C2.ID < C1.id) < 4) Q2 ON Q2.post = Q1.id
ORDER BY Q1.ID
```

**Для произвольного дерева и на Transact-SQL - портировать на MySQL будет нетрудно при должной сноровке.
Перфекционистский зуд. Добавляю корректное формирование поля для сотрировки дерева**

```
CREATE TABLE #tree (
    id INTEGER, parent INTEGER, Lvl INTEGER, idx VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @level INT, @RC INT, @lead0 INT, @pfix VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @lead0 = FLOOR(LOG10(MAX(id))) FROM comments
SET @pfix = REPLICATE('0', @lead0)
SET @level = 0

INSERT INTO #tree 
SELECT id, NULL, @level, LEFT(RIGHT(@pfix+CAST(id AS VARCHAR(255)), @lead0+1), 255)
FROM comments
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @RC > 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tree 
    SELECT C.id, C.parent_id, @level+1, 
LEFT(T.idx+'.'+RIGHT(@pfix+CAST(C.id AS VARCHAR(255)), @lead0+1), 255)

    FROM comments C
        JOIN #tree T ON  T.id = C.parent_id
    WHERE T.lvl = @level

    SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT

    SET @level = @level + 1
END

SELECT * 
FROM #tree
    JOIN comments C ON C.ID = T.id
ORDER BY idx

DROP TABLE #tree
```

Comment: renegator, поможете составить похожий запрос с древовидными комментами?

Comment: соблаговолите пояснить

Comment: Имеется: 2 таблицы. (comment, user).
comment: id, id_user, parent_id, text, date // Это комментарии, где parent_id - ответ на другой комментарий
user: id_user, imya, first_photo // таблица юзеров, кот. оставили коммент.
Запрос:
- 10 ком. родительских (у кот. parent_id = 0);
- для каждого род-го коммета ответы в кол-ве 4-х (у кот. parent_id = id этого ком-ия);
- из таблицы user - данные поля для каждого автора коммента (как ролительского, так и дочернего (ответа))
- и колличество всех ответов на каждый ком-ий-родитель
- сортировка по полю date таблицы comment.
Здесь дважды обращаемся к comment

Comment: В принципе запрос работающий у меня, только ответы выводит все. не могу добавить чтобы он выводил тоже например 4 последних.

Comment: Вообще то запрос в ответе конечно работоспособен, но я его привел только чтобы продемонстрировать возможности SQL и получить заслуженные аплодисменты. Обратите внимание - условие в подзапросе Q2: (SELECT COUNT(*)..)<4 - весьма затратное. При достаточно большом размере базы, а оно будет очень скоро достигнуто, запрос будет работать дольше, чем 10 более простых запросов с условием LIMIT 4

Comment: Всё понятно, тогда эта идея отметается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким алгоритмом воспользоваться, дабы достич задуманного. Напрашивается рекурсия. Но это тоже не вариант. Может UNION присоединить? Натолкните на мысль.

Comment: Построить дерево произвольной глубины? Ну стандартная для меня схема такая - сейчас приведу в ответе

Comment: в-общем, рабочего MySQL под рукой нет, только Oracle и MS SQL

Comment: При кол-ве >10К записей будет долго думать... очень долго.